# Что более точнее определяет местоположения Google Play Services location api или LocationManager

Tags: android, locationmanager

Что более точнее определяет местоположения Google Play Services location api или LocationManager? и какое вы используете?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Самое лучшее, что можно использовать - это [FusedLocationProviderApi](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi).

А лучше тем, что Вам не придется писать свои костыли в `LocationManager` для определения местоположения в таких случаях, как `GPS`, `Network Provider` и *вместе* (а если не подключен? и т.д.). `FusedLocation` включает себя много полезных колбэков, которые могли греть вашу голову, используя `LocationManager`.

[Пример](http://www.androidwarriors.com/2015/10/fused-location-provider-in-android.html)

Да и вообще `FusedLocationProviderApi` - это новый стандарт, а значит, в скором времени, всем придется его использовать.

---

По поводу точности... хмм. Неважно, что использовать... Будь это `lm` или `fused`.

За точность отвечает [следующее](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest):

- `PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY` - GPS + Wi-Fi + Bluetooth + Network.
- `PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY` - Wi-FI + Bluetooth + Network.
- `PRIORITY_LOW_POWER` - только GPS.

---

### Вывод

1. Изучить нужно `LocationManager`(лишним не будет!) и `FusedLocationProviderApi`.
2. Использовать `FusedLocationProviderApi`.
3. `PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY` - точнее только в фильмах.